# Proguard returned with error code 1 when I try to export for apk

Tags: android, eclipse

```
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Proguard returned with error code 1. See console
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find superclass or interface android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.NativeAdView: can't find referenced method 'FrameLayout(android.content.Context,android.util.AttributeSet,int,int)' in class android.widget.FrameLayout
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector$Builder
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$Callback
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.cast.CastRemoteDisplayLocalService$1: can't find referenced class android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter$RouteInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$SessionInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced class android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$SessionInfo
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil: can't find referenced method 'android.content.pm.PackageInstaller getPackageInstaller()' in class android.content.pm.PackageManager
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza: can't find referenced method 'android.app.Notification$Builder setColor(int)' in class android.app.Notification$Builder
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.iid.MessengerCompat: can't find referenced field 'int sendingUid' in class android.os.Message
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzig: can't find referenced method 'void setMixedContentMode(int)' in class android.webkit.WebSettings
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: there were 29 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] Warning: there were 5 unresolved references to program class members.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]  at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]  at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]  at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2015-10-13 13:32:49 - MainWindow]  at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

I have a problem with proguard . i get this big exceptionon in the console(eclipse) .. Please tell me what all lines should i add in my proguard file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ignore the warnings in your config:

For GMS write this:

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

For the other warnings it is the same, exclude the packages.

Comment: It says now that the "export failed for the application"

Comment: thanq so much..:) It kind of worked but sometimes it still says the "export failed for the application"

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project a long time ago, make sure you are using the SDK Proguard configuration file in your project.properties file.

Change

```
proguard.config=proguard.cfg
```

to

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Project.properties :

```
             proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
             available properties: sdk.dir
```

Proguard-project.txt :

```
            -dontwarn org.ini4j.**  //your class which gives warning
```